# Why java bytecode from a class have come code for new staic inner class appear jvm instruction ACONST_NULL

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode, jvm-bytecode

I try to new a inner staic class, But I find that bytecode appear the jvm instruction `ACONST_NULL` bwteen `NEW`,`DUP` and `INVOKE_SPECIAL`,
But I know about a class new is

- NEW
- DUP
- INVOKE_SPECIAL

```java
package com.hoho.api;

/**
 * @author linuxea
 */
public class Main {

    private static class InnerMain {
        // no field
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InnerMain innerMain = new InnerMain();
    }

}
```

```
// class version 52.0 (52)
// access flags 0x21
public class com/hoho/api/Main {

  // compiled from: Main.java
  // access flags 0xA
  private static INNERCLASS com/hoho/api/Main$InnerMain com/hoho/api/Main InnerMain
  // access flags 0x1008
  static synthetic INNERCLASS com/hoho/api/Main$1 null null

  // access flags 0x1
  public <init>()V
   L0
    LINENUMBER 6 L0
    ALOAD 0
    INVOKESPECIAL java/lang/Object.<init> ()V
    RETURN
   L1
    LOCALVARIABLE this Lcom/hoho/api/Main; L0 L1 0
    MAXSTACK = 1
    MAXLOCALS = 1

  // access flags 0x9
  public static main([Ljava/lang/String;)V
    // parameter  args
   L0
    LINENUMBER 13 L0
    NEW com/hoho/api/Main$InnerMain
    DUP
    ACONST_NULL
    INVOKESPECIAL com/hoho/api/Main$InnerMain.<init> (Lcom/hoho/api/Main$1;)V
    ASTORE 1
   L1
    LINENUMBER 14 L1
    RETURN
   L2
    LOCALVARIABLE args [Ljava/lang/String; L0 L2 0
    LOCALVARIABLE innerMain Lcom/hoho/api/Main$InnerMain; L1 L2 1
    MAXSTACK = 3
    MAXLOCALS = 2
}
```

Why

```java
 L0
    LINENUMBER 13 L0
    NEW com/hoho/api/Main$InnerMain
    DUP
    ACONST_NULL
    INVOKESPECIAL com/hoho/api/Main$InnerMain.<init> (Lcom/hoho/api/Main$1;)V
    ASTORE 1
```

What is the `ACONST_NULL`?

Comment: Private nested classes are placed in different `.class` files, but classes in the same top-level context have to have a way to interact with each other; this is the reason for your synthetic inner class. The compiler creates [hidden special-purpose members](https://www.infoworld.com/article/2073578/java-s-synthetic-methods.html) to allow for communication that would otherwise be forbidden by access rules. I suspect that the `null` comes from the fact that the nested class is static (and thus has no `Outer.this`). Try removing the `static` modifier from the nested class and see what you get.

Comment: Mind that you can [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) an answer.

Answer (score 7):

This is the way how `javac` solves private member access problem before JDK 11.

`InnerMain` is declared private, and it has private default constructor:

```
private InnerMain() {
}
```

According to the JVM specification, no class may access private members of other classes, but according to Java language rules, `Main` should be able to access private members of `InnerMain`. To solve this problem, `javac` generates a synthetic package private bridge constructor. To ensure this constructor is not called directly from user code, compiler adds a dummy class `Main$1` in the signature:

```
// Real constructor
private InnerMain() {
}


// Synthetic bridge constructor (package private, so Main can call it)
InnerMain(Main$1 dummy) {
    this();
}
```

When you write `new InnerMain()`, the compiler actually calls this bridge constructor. The actual value of the dummy argument does not matter, so it's just set to `null` - hence `ACONST_NULL` instruction:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    InnerMain innerMain = new InnerMain(null);
}
```

Note that bridge methods are not needed when the inner class is public or package private.

Since JDK 11, a fundamentally new mechanism was introduced, see [JEP 181: Nest-Based Access Control](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/181). Now, if you compile your Main class with JDK 11 or newer, `Main` and `InnerMain` will become nestmates and will be able to access private members of each other without bridge methods and synthetic classes.

Comment: Yes, when I make the visibility of the inner class default constructor higher than private, the synthetic bridge constructor disappears.

Comment: Emmm.I get a another question. 
' Main should be able to access private members of InnerMain. To solve this problem, javac generates a synthetic package private bridge constructor. '
Why a bridge constructor can make Main be able to access private members of InnerMain?

Comment: @Linuxea Because `Main` accesses package private bridge constructor instead of the private original constructor. And the bridge constructor in turn delegates to the original private constructor of the same class.

Comment: But generating an entire class just for the sake of having a dummy parameter to tell the the original constructor and the synthetic one apart, is quite heavy. I think, even if it is never instantiated (hence not initialized), it has to be loaded to be able to invoke a constructor having it as parameter type. Eclipse just used the inner class itself for the dummy parameter instead of generating another one and it also works.

Comment: But in either case, adding a dummy parameter can have funny consequences (when maxing out the number of parameters); a formerly correctly accepted private constructor may get rejected when we add a caller from a nested class, because now it has “too many parameters”. Whereas removing the `private` modifier makes the compiler error go away. Thankfully, that’s past now.